# CHAID package installed from source in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I have installed `CHAID` package in R for Windows in the following way:

1. installed the `Rtools31.exe`
2. installed the package from source: `install.packages("CHAID", repos = "http://R-Forge.R-project.org", type = "source")`

When I try to see the help documentation for CHAID I run : ?CHAID()
the following error message appears:

```
"Error in .helpForCall(topicExpr, parent.frame()) : 
  no methods for ‘chaid’ and no documentation for it as a function"
```

This means the `CHAID` package hasn't been installed?
when I run the `installed.packages()` the following line appears:

```
        Package                                        LibPath   Version   Priority     
CHAID   "CHAID"  "C:/Users/JJJJJJ/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"   "0.1-1"         NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you write it appears that you have installed the `CHAID` package correctly. To use it within R, you need to load the package via

```
library("CHAID")
```

and the main fitting function is `chaid()`. To view its manual page you can use either one of

```
?chaid
help("chaid", package = "CHAID")
```

and some examples can be carried out by

```
example("chaid", package = "CHAID")
```